# echo result from compare 2 table sql in 1 database

Tags: php, sql, arrays

database name : test
table name : employee
structur

```
+-----+------------+----------+--------+
| id  | name       | Password |  code  |
+-----+------------+----------+--------+
| 11  | John       | test122  |   A1   |
| 12  | Johana     | test124  |   A2   |
| 13  | David      | test125  |   A3   |
| 14  | Anna       | test126  |   A1   |
| 15  | Mike       | test127  |   A5   |
+-----+------------+----------+--------+
```

table name : code_id
structur

```
+-------+------------+
| code  | codename   |
+-------+------------+
| A1    | Security   |
| A2    | Manager    |
| A3    | Admin      |
| A4    | guest      |
| A5    | CEO        |
+-------+------------+
```

i want to say welcome and it success

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM employee";
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $idcode = $row['code'];
      }
    mysql_close();
```

echo $idcode
result:
welcome, A1

---

now i want 
to echo
welcome, Manager
or
welcome CEO

how to query that on php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
$strSQL = "select a.*,b.codename from employee as a join code_id as b on a.code=b.code";
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $idcode = $row['codename'];
      }
    mysql_close();
```

Comment: then how to echo on php ?

Answer (score 0):

An easier way without querying can be this,

```
<?php
function convertCode($code) {
    $codes = [
        "A1" => "Security",
        "A2" => "Manager",
        "A3" => "Admin",
        "A4" => "guest",
        "A5" => "CEO"
    ];
    return $codes[$code];
}
?>
```

Then in your loop,

```
echo "Welcome " . convertCode($row['code']) . ".";
```

**Edit 1**

You shouldn't be using `mysql` any more as it has been officially deprecated. You should change to `mysqli` or `PDO`.